# How do I include a javascript library on Rails 5?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

It is the first time that I will deal with a javascript library in rails. In this case, I'm going to use TrackingJS to work with facial recognition, but as I never used it, I don't know how to include it in my project and use it.

I use rails 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different methods have developed over time, the older one is called the Asset Pipeline: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

The newer one is a gem called Webpacker: https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/

The breadth and width of the differences here is two wide to express in a SO answer, but suffice it to say, the default in Rails 5 is the former and the default in Rails 6 is the latter.

Here's some information on how to add NPM modules, like the one you brought up, to the asset pipeline: https://ricostacruz.com/til/npm-in-rails

However, I'd say you're probably better off just understanding and learning Webpacker and either adding it to your Rails 5 project, or porting your project to Rails 6 as well. It really doesn't take that long and Webpacker is a better choice moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you download external libraries into the `vendor/assets` folder. For TrackingJS you could create a `tracking_js` folder and download the JavaScript files they provide. Either from their [website](https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#introduction) or a production version from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tracking.js).

Depending on the chosen file you now have the `vendor/assets/tracking_js/tracking-min.js` file. You can include it in your project using `//= require tracking-min` in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file.

If the JavaScript makes use of certain assets that are also provided you'll need to change the script from `.js` to `.js.erb` and uses the `asset_path` helper to refer to the file location.

Popular libraries often have a Rails gem available where this is all done for you. For example [leaflet-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/leaflet-rails) is such a library that makes use of assets (SVG markers), and is available as gem where those actions are already performed. JavaScript libraries without assets can stay as is, most of the time you wont find gems for them, since you simply drop them in your `vendor/assets/<library>/` folder.

For further info check out [2.2 Asset Organization](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) from The [Asset Pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) guide.